# Не получается обход некоторых директорий

Tags: c#

Нужно обойти этот список папок

```
private static readonly List<string> Dir = new List<string>
{
  "Windows", "SysWow64", "Microsoft", "System32"
};
```

Пытаюсь запилить его в этот метод поиска файлов

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
   var foldersToProcess = new List<string>() { path };

   while (foldersToProcess.Count > 0)
   {
      string folder = foldersToProcess[0];
      foldersToProcess.RemoveAt(0);

      if (searchOption.HasFlag(SearchOption.AllDirectories))
      {
        //get subfolders
        try
        {
           string[] subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);
           foreach (string ss in Dir)
           {
              if (!subfolders.Contains(ss)) // тут пробую обойти эти папки
              {
                 foldersToProcess.AddRange(subfolders);
              }
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ) { }
      }

      //get files
      var files = new List<string>();
      try
      {
          files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
      }
      catch (Exception) { }

      foreach (string file in files)
      {
         yield return file;
      }
   }
}
```

Но в итоге всё ровно заходит в папки C:\Windows и.т.д подскажите что я не так делаю?

Comment: `Нужно обойти этот список папок` ... `"Windows",` ... `Но в итоге всё ровно заходит в папки C:\Windows` ?

Comment: @tym32167, Да системные папки.

Comment: Как их правильно обходить? Я пробовал и полные пути в `List<string>` давать, ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Запусти программу с правами администратора.

Если запускаешь из Visual Studio, то её саму запусти с правами администратора.

И скомпилируй программу под x64.

Comment: Вне студии запускаю от Админа, и студия запущена от Админа, что через саму студию что из вне один и тот же результат. Но мне нужно сделать обход некоторых папок)) А как это правильно сделать не получается

Comment: @Luser, дополнил.

Comment: А почему anycpu не катит?

Comment: @Luser, потому что виртуализация, скорее всего.